# How can I create a textarea that can contain strings and links like in a blog post using Yup schema?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, yup, react-forms

```
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    title: yup.string().required("Your post should have a title"),
    description: yup.string().required("Your post should have a description"),
    image: yup.string().required("Add an image for your post"),
    createdOn: date().default(() => new Date()),
  });
```

In this case the textarea is the description.

I used the code above but I can just return only strings. I want an input that can detect strings and as well links

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking into a wysiwig editor first and foremost if you want a single input that can display multiple datatypes.  Wysiwig editors store the data as a string of html tags allowing for that "textarea" to display images, links and text.  Yup also has no concept of links or images as far as I am aware so you need to find a way to assert those things yourself.

One way of doing so would be to use yup matches to assert that specific html tags (, ) are present using regex. i.e

```
description: Yup.string()
    .matches(/<a>/, 'You must provide a link')
    .matches(/<img>/, 'You must provide an image').....,
```

That is a very basic set of tests, there will be more efficient regex and ways to chain the yup rules, but that is the basic idea.  Look into the Yup docs for test(), matches() etc to get a good understanding of how to properly leverage its power!

---

If you are storing everything separate however (and using multiple inputs to do so) like your Yup suggests, you will have to create matches and tests based on fileTypes for images, http/https for links like so

```
 const schema = yup.object().shape({
    title: yup.string().required("Your post should have a title"),
    description: yup.string().required("Your post should have a description"),
    image: yup.string().matches(/\.(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|webp|bmp)$/, "Not an image file type" ).required("Add an image for your post"),
    createdOn: date().default(() => new Date()),
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank, I will look into wysiwig asap.